# Reactjs Boostrap Table Get ID?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use `formatExtraData` to pass a row ID to the Icon function.

I don't know how I can access this from the row ID from another table's column.

The ID (from the data) is not generated.

How can I solve this problem?

```
<TableHeaderColumn
 dataField='Topic_ID'
 width="15%"
 isKey hidden
 dataSort>
ID
</TableHeaderColumn>
<TableHeaderColumn
dataField='icon'
dataFormat={Icon}
//  formatExtraData={}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this `{(e)=>Icon(e,'Topic_ID')}`.

```
  </TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn
    dataField='icon'
    dataFormat={(e)=>Icon(e,'Topic_ID')}
    //  formatExtraData={}
    >
```

or you can do this without passing id in Icon function

```
Icon = (e) =>{
console.log(e.target.getAttribute("dataField"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, could you please explain me what is Icon(ID). I try it and it said ID is not defined.

Comment: I am assuming that `ID` is a variable with `ID` namespace  that you are trying to pass in `Icon` function if you have different namespace then `ID` then replace with that.

Comment: How to create ID namespace and get Topic_ID from ID cell? To clarify, my Icon function is an icon with a link. I want to update the link base on which row is selected. Therefore, I have Topic_ID in data but I do not know how to pass it to the Icon function.

Comment: You want to pass "Topic_ID" to Icon function  which is set in dataField attribute right?

Comment: Yes. I would like to do that.